# error when parsing json on windows phone 7

Tags: json, windows-phone-7

I followed tutorial from [here](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/search/label/JSON)

but when I want to implement it with my own json, I got an error message

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BelajarJson.RootObject]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'err_code', line 2, position 13.

Content.cs

```
namespace BelajarJson
{
    public class Content
    {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int timestamp { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Paging.cs

```
namespace BelajarJson
{
public class Paging
{
    public int current_page { get; set; }
    public int total_page { get; set; }
    public int total_all { get; set; }
    public int limit_per_page { get; set; }
}
}
```

RootObject.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BelajarJson
{
public class RootObject
{
    public int err_code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Paging paging { get; set; }
    public List<Content> contents { get; set; }
}
}
```

MainPage.xaml.xs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Reactive;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace BelajarJson
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {




        var w = new WebClient();
        Observable
          .FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(w, "DownloadStringCompleted")
          .Subscribe(r =>
          {
              var deserialized =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(r.EventArgs.Result);
              PhoneList.ItemsSource = deserialized;
          });
        w.DownloadStringAsync(
          new Uri("http://yumugee.com/json.txt"));
    }
}
}
```

I've tried to google and search same problem from here but still no luck.
do you have some advices how to solve this problem? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed that your results are actually an array of objects, and not just a single object. The constructor for a List() can take an IEnumerable, like an array, but not a single object.

JSON array should look something like [{"name":"value"},{"name":"value"}]